# SpringBatch5 migration Junits fail with BadSQLGrammer after adding @EnableBatchProcessing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am migrating from SB 2.x to SB 3.x and I am aware that @EnableBatchProcessing is not recomended but as i need to use a custom JacksonSearlizer I am using @EnableBatchProcessing(executionContextSerializerRef="myJacksonSerializer")

**But the tests which were fine using SBatch 4 & SBatch 5(without
EnableBatchProcessing)
If we add @EnableBatchProcessing we get Bad SQL grammmer errors for H2 DB**